# Is it possible to find your own IP address by using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, security, pdf, ip, adobe

I am creating a grade report form for my college using Adobe Acrobat. The PDF takes the answers, calculates the result, then generates an email to both professor and student with the results. The report is being made for classes where students demonstrate proficiency with medical practices and procedures. I am a beginner when it comes to javascript, but I do know that Adobe ONLY uses javascript, which may limit what I am able to work with.

I know that I can call the browser and OS, but I was hoping that I could 'sign' the device's IP address and/or mac address that generates that report, since it would not be theoretically difficult for a student to change their grades and claim that the instructor is lying. I already have the form set all form fields to read-only on creation of the report, then unlocking itself for the next exam. I want to try to either attach the address as a part of the document's metadata or into a form field in the document.

I want to ensure that there is more than just one level of protection on the form (not just for the school or instructor, but for the student too). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: probably not, but can you inject a unique serial number into the pdf that you can sign and use to ID specific student's copy of the file?

Comment: That's a really great idea.

Comment: You cannot get the IP of the localhost from within the PDF file. You can easily query the internet for the hosts IP address, but that can be blocked. You will be better served by using the most excellent electronic signature capability built into Adobe reader.

Comment: Which IP? A computer likely has several. There is `localhost`, there is the loopback range starting from `127.0.0.1` there is the local LAN IP often something like `192.168.1.42` but you also have an external IP (often NATed) or even multiple. You might have a VPN, you might have proxies in front of the machine. You often also have an IPv4 and IPv6 address. You might have any number of IPs assigned to virtual machines and docker containers and such. On top of all that, IPs aren't even unique.

Comment: This: https://helpx.adobe.com/reader/using/fill-and-sign.html